# Edit "Places" in main menu, Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome Classic

Tags: gnome-classic, trash, menu-bar, places

When I left-click on the "Main Menu" icon on my control panel (if that's what we call it) it pulls up a menu with sub-menus for "System Tools" etc. but also one called "Places" that opens various folder windows.

I can edit the applications part of the menu by right-clicking on the menu icon, but I don't see a provision to edit the "Places" list. (I'd like to add the "Trash" folder, for example).
How do I do this?

Comment: There are a lot of postings about editing the places pane in the folder windows.
I'm not asking about that, I'm askin about the Places sub-menu in the main menu.

Comment: According to [an article on OMGUbuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/enable-gnome-classic-mode-ubuntu) you cannot customize this further. They also suggest that if you try, it will break things. This is still GNOME3 after all!

Answer (score 0):

There are limited possibilities to edit that menu indeed. You can add regular folders which will appear in the third section of the menu by bookmarking them. Bookmarks will appear in the left pane of files, and also will appear in the places menu.

With a hack, you can also add special locations such as "Trash" to your bookmarks. Open the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` and add `trash:///` on a new line. The Trash will now appear in the bookmark section of the Places menu. A drawback of the approach is that it now appears twice in different sections in the left pane of Files.